# Is it possible to redirect after payment on paypal.me?

Tags: html, redirect, paypal, payment, payment-processing

Is it possible to redirect users to a landing "successful payment" page after a payment on paypal.me? This is the "Auto Return" feature on PayPal but I'm not sure if it's available for paypal.me, or if there might be other creative solutions available. The user needs to fill out a form after payment, which is why a redirect to the successful payment / form page would be great.

I tried embedding PayPal.me, and I tried turning on AutoReturn. This didn't work to redirect it to the specified website. Embedding failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need one of Paypal's [integrations](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/) to do that.